# How to change sql code to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have this script running on sql, but i need to optimize it to mysql using the workbench, but it shows me an error in the foreign key and i don't know how to change it.

```
create table EspecialidadesMedicas(
IdEspecialidad int(4) primary key,
DescripcionEspecialidad varchar(30));

create table Doctores(
IdDoctor int(5) PRIMARY KEY,
NombreDoctor varchar(30),
Salario int(12.2),
Especialidad int(4),citascitas
Especialidad FOREIGN KEY references EspecialidadesMedicas(IdEspecialidad));
```

Comment: `Especialidad int(4),citascitas
Especialidad` - Is there any typo here?

Comment: Is there space in your column name `citascitas Especialidad`? and what is `int(12.2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working syntax:

```
create table EspecialidadesMedicas (
    IdEspecialidad int(4) primary key,
    DescripcionEspecialidad varchar(30)
);

create table Doctores(
    IdDoctor int(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    NombreDoctor varchar(30),
    Salario int(12),
    Especialidad int(4),
    citascitas varchar(30),
    constraint fk_Especialidad FOREIGN KEY (Especialidad) references EspecialidadesMedicas(IdEspecialidad)
   );
```